# c++ create an instance of the class as a reference type

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, instance

Create a Bond class and a MuniBond class that inherits from Bond. Create a simple program and create an instance of the MuniBond class as a reference type.

Don't know how to create an instance of the MuniBond class as a reference type.

Bond.h

```
#pragma once

class Bond 
{
private:
    int myValue;
public:
    int a;
};
```

Bond.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Bond.h"


class MuniBond : public Bond 
{
private:
    int myValue;

public:
    MuniBond(int);
    ~MuniBond(void);
    void set_Value(int);
    int get_Value();
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Bond.h"
#include "MuniBond.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _main()
{
     MuniBond *m_obj = new MuniBond (5);

     cout << m_obj->get_Value()<<endl;
    delete m_obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that, instead of posting homework questions, you post your attempts at solving the homework problem along with commentary as to what you think you're doing and what you think isn't working.

Comment: Here's the code I made. However, there's some error. Like : LNK2019......

Comment: Where is the actual code for the constructor, destructor, etc.? The linker will need them.

Answer (score 0):

"Reference type" is a strange choice of word from your teacher.  It actually has a very specific meaning, but isn't quite related to what the question is asking (using the usual meanings of the word, you can't create an "instance" that is a reference type... you have to create a "variable" that is a reference type).  You should review your class notes to determine what the teacher means.

If I had to venture a guess, I would guess that they want you to create an instance of a MuniBond, and then create a variable whose type is a "reference type" which refers to it.  Reference types are notated using the `&` symbol, so a `int&` is a "reference to an int"

If this is the correct interpretation of your teacher's word choice, then you are almost there!  You created an instance of your Munibond already, and you've stored a pointer to it (`m_obj`).  All we need to do is create a variable which is a "reference to a MuniBond," or `MuniBond&` and have it refer to the object `m_obj` is pointing at.  This is easy to do by "dereferencing" `m_obj` using `*`.  Dereferencing is a C++ operator that takes a pointer to some instance object (which you have), and produces a reference to that object (which you want).  Given that you already have pointers in your code, you've probably used this `*` operator already.  If not, I recommend reading up on it, because its very powerful, and I'm not focusing on it right now.

The final line you would need (assuming I translate your teacher's wording properly), is something along the lines of

```
MuniBond& m_refToObj = *m_obj;
```

now `m_refToObj` is a reference to the same instance that `m_obj` points at.

Answer (score 0):

A reference type is denoted with `&` (as opposed to a pointer which is specified with `*`). You can think of a reference as being akin to an implicit pointer.

As a matter of good practice, avoid using `new` unless absolutely necessary, and if you do, wrapping it in a `unique_ptr` or one of the other pointer management types is a good idea.

To get a reference:

`MuniBond m_Obj(5); //stack-based instantiation
MuniBond& m_ObjRef = m_Obj;`

Alternatively, in C++11 you can use an rvalue-reference (`&&`) which will take ownership of an rvalue instantiation and keep the object "alive" past the line it existed on.

`MuniBond&& m_ObjRvalRef = MuniBond(5);`